Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'join')
В проекте nestjs в одном сервисе попытался использовать path.join(), но при запуске проекта выдаётся ошибка:
PS D:\VS Code Projects\zinkova-site-server> npm start

> zinkova-site-server@0.0.1 start
> nest start

[Nest] 11700  - 31.12.2024, 23:12:49     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 11700  - 31.12.2024, 23:12:49   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'access')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'access')

Вот сам сервис:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import multer from 'multer';
import path from 'path';
import { checkOrCreate } from './checkOrCreateDir';
import e from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class FilesService {
    imagesPath: string;
    descriptionsPath: string;
    storage: multer.StorageEngine;
    upload: e.RequestHandler;

    constructor() {
        this.imagesPath = path.join('jfvn', 'files/images');
        //this.descriptionsPath = path.join(global.appDir, 'files/descriptions');
        //checkOrCreate(this.imagesPath);
        //checkOrCreate(this.descriptionsPath);

        // const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        //     destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        //         cb(null, this.imagesPath);
        //     },
        //     filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        //         cb(null, `${Date.now()}-${file.originalname}`); // Имя файла
        //     },
        // });

        // this.upload = multer({ storage }).single('image');
    }

    // async saveImage(file: any) {
    //     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //         this.upload(file, {}, (err: any) => {
    //             if (err) {
    //                 reject(err);
    //             } else {
    //                 resolve(`/uploads/images/${file.filename}`);
    //             }
    //         });
    //     });
    // }
}

Как видите, я долго ломал голову над проблемой. Единственная идея, к которой я пришёл - nest создаёт объект сервиса для внедрения зависимости до того, как происходят импорты в файле сервиса.
Изменено: использование require решает проблему. Вроде как моя версия подтверждается. Но как конкретно проблема решилась и можно ли всё-таки заставить работать import - вопрос всё ещё остаётся.

пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

посмотрите здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553291/can-you-import-nodes-path-module-using-import-path-from-path
Проблема указывает на то что path -> undefined, т.е. не заимпортировался
